# drop unnamed contraints in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a program with [msaccess] and i need rename the column of a table. The problem is that i can not rename with a sql statement if the column is indexed, so I have to delete the index.

To delete the index i use:

```
ALTER TABLE SuministroProductos DROP CONSTRAINT Index_84793306_29F5_4DFF
```

But not in all versions, does the index have the same name.

So, how can i know the name of the index in each table?
Is there another way of renaming the column? I need with SQL instructions in access.

Thank you

EDIT:
This work:

```
DROP INDEX Index_BB8ACAF4_28D7_4339 ON SuministroProductos
```

But this not work:

```
DROP INDEX Index_* ON SuministroProductos
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will iterate through the indexes of your table.

```
For i = 0 to CurrentDb.TableDefs("SuministroProductos").Indexes.Count - 1
   IndexArray(i) = CurrentDb.TableDefs("SuministroProductos").Indexes(i).Name
Next
```

Comment: Ok, and how can i get the Object CurrentDB? Because i send sql instruccions to the database with Oledb.connection. Thank you

Comment: `CurrentDb` is available in VBA. Just open a Module in the VBA editor and use the above there.

Comment: Can i open this in my VB.Net project? I need do it there

Comment: @Millas - in a VB.Net project, if you've added the Access library as a reference, the `CurrentDb` object should be available inside an Access application object that you create.

Comment: I have not added the Access library, I use the `OleDb` object.